# Better way to edit Last item in Foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have

```
var queryString = "";
foreach (var q in query)
{
    if (q.Equals(query.Last())
    {
       queryString += "'" + q.Trim() + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        queryString += "'" + q.Trim() + "', ";
    }
}
return queryString;
```

However it feels rather clunky and unsophisticated. I'm convinced there is a better way to do it, but I haven't the foggiest, and Googling hasn't provided any better suggestions either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var queryString = string.Join(",", query.Select(item=>$"'{item.Trim()}'"));
```

Essentially, you declare a sequence of the items that are in the `query` by Trimming them and enclosing them in single quotes and the using the `string.Join` you create a comma separated list of them.

Comment: That is elegant and very much fits the one-liner I was looking for.

Comment: @gilliduck Thanks :)

Comment: @gilliduck from what I can tell you are bulding SQL query? if this is the case don't use this solution this way is unsecure and is open for SQL injection.

Comment: @gilliduck Filip is correct, *provided that you are trying to build a SQL query*. I say provided that, because his comment is an assumption, it's not pretty clear what you are trying to do. If he is correct and you try to write a sql query this way, you should handle it totally different, using parameters and not string concatenation.